# Defining scope configuration/solution targeting by ARM Template or Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm-template, azure-log-analytics

I have Automation Account linked with Log Analytics Workspace and Updates solution enable on it. Evrything has been created automatically by ARM Templates or Terraform code and I am trying to find any way how can I add solution targeting for Update Management only for particular VMs. When I add this solution by Azure Portal and link Automation Account with Log Analytics workspace from Update Management menu, it added automatically "MicrosoftDefaultScopeConfig-Updates" scope.

Is there any way to add scope by ARM Template or Terraform code? Or maybe with other automatically way for example as Powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

Related / Duplicate question is raised in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4286641-1f34-46d9-9580-d2387c89d61b/defining-scope-configurationsolution-targeting-by-arm-template?forum=opinsights) MSDN thread; Just sharing this for the benefit of broader audience who might face similar issue and might look for an answer.

Comment: Hi KrishnaG-MSFT, this does not help us, using that link I didn't find any useful information. We are trying to automate Update Management onboarding process, so we want to use prepared, based on Saved Search, Computer Groups, and then use these Computer Groups to prepare Solution Targeting.